# JSON mapping of parameter- issue with '\'

Tags: objective-c, json, post, mapping, nsdictionary

the expected raw data`(application/json)` from postman for `POST` API is as follows:

```
{"survey_answer":{"answers_json": "{\"4090442c-90ce-42c2-aae8-7c812b7c0f04\":\"test from postman\"}"}}
```

how do you I generalise the parameter to be sent to the API request?
Is it a dictionary? if so how do I initialise it?`4090442c-90ce-42c2-aae8-7c812b7c0f04` is the survey id depending on the question being answered and "test from postman" is the answer entered through textfield.

Thanks! @Larme am getting surveyAnswerForCurrentSurvey as string so
I tired the below code on updating the value for key "f884a7d1-f9d9-4563-bb6e-94538664f3bd" :-

```
NSData *data = [surveyAnswerForCurrentSurvey dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *answerJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
NSMutableDictionary *answer = [answerJson mutableCopy];
if([answer valueForKey:question.name] != nil){
    [answer setObject:textField.text forKey:question.name];
}
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[answer copy] options:0 error:nil];
NSLog(@"ns data is %@",jsonData);
NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"json string:%@", json);
NSDictionary *answersDict = @{@"answers_json":json};
NSData *answersAsData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: answersDict options:0 error:nil];
NSString *answersJSONStringify = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: answersAsData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
parameters = @{@"survey_answer":answersJSONStringify};
```

but its giving me the result as
{
    "survey_answer" = "{\"answers_json\":\"{\\"7d2c591c-9056-405c-9509-03266842b7e5\\":[\\"1\\"],\\"54bdcf13-e500-418a-8bab-d0639e7e1e28\\":\\"2\\",\\"63bb0722-7099-4820-a400-36b8938c6ae8\\":\\"hello\\",\\"f884a7d1-f9d9-4563-bb6e-94538664f3bd\\":\\"test from cms\\",\\"ed3acc20-4ae4-493e-ac55-4d2d0f282886\\":\\"1\\"}\"}";
}

so am getting '\\' in the final result hence the request parameter is not in proper format. how to avoid them?

Comment: I found the code snippet in postman                                         NSDictionary *parameters = @{ @"survey_answer": @{ @"answers_json": @"{\"4090442c-90ce-42c2-aae8-7c812b7c0f04\":\"test from postman\"}" } };
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:0 error:nil];     But how to make it dynamic i.e., with value/text entered from textfield and key as surveyQuestionId

Comment: `NSDictionary *answersDict = @{@"answers_json": @{"4090442c-90ce-42c2-aae8-7c812b7c0f04":"test from postman"}; NSData *answersAsData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: answersDict options:0 error:nil]; NSString *answersJSONStringify = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: answersAsData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; NSDictionary *parameters = @[@"survey_answer:answersJSONStringify]; NSData *postData = theSame as you did`? It's JSON within JSON, just do it piece by piece and set your own values wherever you want.

Comment: Thanks @Larme .Please see my below answer